# axios does not send image to server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm using axios to send image to server, but my server return this error:
"The image field is required."

*HTML tag:*

```
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg" @change="updateImage" />
```

*Vue.js method:*

```
updateImage(event) {
    let data = new FormData();

    data.append("image", event.target.files[0]);

    axios.put("http://localhost/api/account/settings/image", data);
},
```

*Laravel validator rule:*

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'image' => ['bail', 'required', 'image', 'between:10,10000'],
    ];
}
```

What is the problem ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use put method with files . it has nothing to do with laravel nor your code [check this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815) .

i would recommand using post request